# How to retrieve CountryName list in a combox from xml object got from stdClass Object array?

Tags: php, arrays, soap

Questions: I have a response from SOAP request as given below where **CountryList** response is XML object with CountryCode & CountryName. So how can I display a combox box having CountryName from the results.?

```
stdClass Object
(
[CountryList] => 
AFAfghanistanALAlbaniaDZAlgeriaASAmerican  amoaADAndorraAOAngolaAIAnguillaAQAntarcticaAGAntigua & BarbudaARArgentinaAMArmeniaAWArubaAUAustraliaATAustriaAZAzerbaijanBSBahamasBHBahrainBDBangladeshBBBarbadosBYBelarus(Belorussia)BEBelgiumBZBelizeBJBeninBMBermudaBTBhutanBOBoliviaBABosnia and HerzegowinaBWBotswanaBVBouvet IslandsBRBrazilIOBritish Indian Ocean TerritoryVGBritish Virgin IslandsBNBrunei DarussalamBGBulgariaBFBurkina FasoBIBurundiKHCambodiaCMCameroonCACanadaCBCanada BufferCVCape VerdeKYCayman IslandsCFCentral African RepublicTDChadCLChileCNChinaCXChristmas IslandsCCCocos (Keeling) IslandCOColombiaKMComorosCGCongoCDCongo (Rep. Dem.)CKCook IslandsCRCosta RicaHRCroatiaCUCubaCYCyprusCZCzech RepublicDKDenmarkDJDjiboutiDODominican RepublicDMDominicanaTPEast TimorECEcuadorEGEgyptSVEl SalvadorGQEquatorial GuineaEREritreaEEEstoniaETEthiopiaEUEuropean Monetary UnionFKFalkland IslandsFOFaroe IslandsFJFiji IslandsFIFinlandFRFranceGFFrench GuianaPFFrench PolynesiaTFFrench Southern TerritoriesGAGabonGMGambiaGEGeorgiaDEGermanyGHGhanaGIGibralterGRGreeceGLGreenlandGDGrenadaGPGuadeloupeGUGuamGTGuatemalaGNGuineaGWGuinea-BissauGYGuyanaHTHaitiHMHeard & Mcdonald IslandsHNHondurasHKHongkongHUHungaryISIcelandINIndiaIDIndonesiaIRIranIQIraqIEIrelandILIsraelITItalyCIIvory CoastJMJamaicaJPJapanJOJordanKZKazakhstanKEKenyaKIKiribatiKPKorea (Democratic People's Republic Of)KWKuwaitKGKyrgyzstanLALao People's Democratic RepublicLVLatviaLBLebanonLSLesothoLRLiberiaLYLibyan Arab JamahiriyaLILiechtensteinLTLithuaniaQLLithuania (Dummy Code)LULuxembourgMOMacauMKMacedoniaMGMadagascarMWMalawiMYMalaysiaMVMaldivesMLMaliMTMaltaMHMarshall IslandsMQMartiniqueMRMauritaniaMUMauritiusYTMayotteMXMexicoMBMexico BufferFMMicronesiaMDMoldovaMCMonacoMNMongoliaMSMontserratMAMoroccoMZMozambiqueMMMyanmarNANamibiaNRNauruNPNepalNLNetherlandsANNetherlands AntillesNCNew CaledoniaNZNew ZealandNINicaraguaNENigerNGNigeriaNUNiueNFNorfolk IslandsMPNorthern Mariana IslandsNONorwayOMOmanPKPakistanPWPalauPSPalestinian Occ. TerritoriesPAPanamaPGPapua New GuineaPYParaguayPEPeruPHPhilippinesPLPolandPTPortugalPRPuerto RicoQAQatarREReunionRORomaniaRWRuandaRURussian FederationLCSaint LuciaWSSamoaSMSan MarinoSTSao Tome & PrincipeSASaudi ArabiaSNSenegalSCSeychellesSLSierra LeoneSGSingaporeSKSlovakiaSISloveniaSBSolomon IslandsSOSomaliaZASouth AfricaGSSouth Georgia & South SandwichKRSouth KoreaSUSoviet UnionESSpainLKSri LankaSHSt. HelenaKNSt. Kitts and NevisPMSt. Pierre & MiquelonVCSt. Vincent & the GrenadinesSDSudanSRSurinameSJSvalbard & Jan Mayen IslandsSZSwazilandSESwedenCHSwitzerlandSYSyrian Arab RepublicTWTaiwanTJTajikistanTZTanzaniaTHThailandTGTogoTKTokelauTOTongaTTTrinidad and TobagoTNTunisiaTCTurcs & Caicos IslandsTRTurkeyTMTurkmenistanTVTuvaluUMU.S. Minor Outlaying IslandsUGUgandaUAUkraineAEUnited Arab EmiratesGBUnited Kingdom UYUruguay USUSAUZUzbekistan VUVanuatuVAVatican City StateVEVenezuelaVNVietnamVIVirgin Islands (US)WFWallis & Futuna IslandsEHWestern SaharaYEYemenYUYugoslaviaZMZambiaZWZimbabwe
[Error] => stdClass Object
(
[ErrorCode] => 0
[ErrorMessage] =>
)
[Status] => 1
[TokenId] => 1d49ba03-173f-49a9-ad07-b758b0ea2fc9
)
```

Comment: I hope you do have some string delimiter not showed here for country code.

Comment: According to SOAP service provider they said that"CountryList" is xml type. But they have mentioned in their help document like  (RESPONSE) "CountryList":"<Countries><Country><Code>AF</Code><Name>Afghanistan</Name></Country><Country><Code>AL</Code><Name>Albania</Name></Country><Country><Code>DZ</Code>
<Name>Algeria</Name></Country><Country><Code>AS</Code><Name>American
Samoa</Name></Country></Countries>", BUT when I print using  print nl2br(print_r($resp_countrylists, true));  it shows the results as shown in QS above.

Comment: Use echo "<pre>"; print_r($xml) to see proper format. Give us the most original format. Don't try to correct it.

Comment: When I tried to display as said by @Demodave  , output comes as AFAfghanistanALAlbaniaDZAlgeriaASAmerican SamoaADAndorraAOAngolaAIAnguillaAQAntarcticaAGAntigua & BarbudaARArgentinaAMArmeniaAWArubaAUAustraliaATAustriaAZAzerbaijanBSBahamasBHBahrainBDBangladeshBBBarbadosBYBelarus (Belorussia)BEBelgiumBZBelizeBJBeninBMBermudaBTBhutanBOBoliviaBABosnia and HerzegowinaBWBotswanaBVBouvet Islands...

Answer (score 0):

Using the string that you gave us you can do this.

```
$str = "<Countries><Country><Code>AF</Code><Name>Afghanistan</Name></Coun‌​try><Country><Code>AL</Code><Name>Albania</Name></Country><Country><Code>DZ</Code‌​> <Name>Algeria</Name></Country><Country><Code>AS</Code><Name>American Samoa</Name></Country></Countries>";

$str = substr_delimeters($str, "<Countries>", "</Countries>");
$countries = explode("</Country>", $str);

echo "<select name='countries'>";

foreach($countries as $country)
{           
    if($country != '')
    {
        $country_name = substr_delimeters($country, "<Name>", "</Name>");

        $country_abrev = substr_delimeters($country, "<Code>", "</Code>");        

        echo "<option value='" . $country_abrev . "'>" . $country_name . "</option>";
    }
}    

echo "</select>";

function substr_delimeters($inputstr,$delimeterLeft,$delimeterRight) {
    if (empty($inputstr) || empty($delimeterLeft) || empty($delimeterRight)) return false;
    $posLeft  = stripos($inputstr,$delimeterLeft)+strlen($delimeterLeft);
    $posRight = stripos($inputstr,$delimeterRight,$posLeft+1);
    if (($posLeft===false) || ($posRight===false)) return false;
    return  substr($inputstr,$posLeft,$posRight-$posLeft);
}
```

Comment: @BINODDEKA If this is an acceptable answer you should check it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use somethis like this

```
$string = "<Countries><Country><Code>AF</Code><Name>Afghanistan</Name></Coun‌​try><Country><Code>AL</Code><Name>Albania</Name></Country><Country><Code>DZ</Code‌​> <Name>Algeria</Name></Country><Country><Code>AS</Code><Name>American Samoa</Name></Country></Countries>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($string);
$countries = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Country');
echo '<select name="countries">';
foreach($countries as $country) {
    $code = $country->getElementsByTagName('Code')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $countryName = $country->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $code, $countryName);
}
echo '</select>';
```